# Video Aspect Ratio Not Vertical

Tags: resolution

I'm trying to create a vertical animation for a YouTube short. I have set the resolution, so it has a greater height than its width. But the rendered animation looks like the vertical was cut out of a standard horizontal 1920x1080, so there are empty sheds on the sides. How do I render this animation, so the aspect vertical ratio is centered or fit to the screen, like a YouTube or Instagram short or reel?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only settings that really do control the output resolution are... The resolution settings:

[image]

It looks like you didn't set a vertical resolution output, but instead used a render region in your camera to try "crop" the render.

But unless you enable "Crop to Render Region", all it will do is restrict the render to the render region and output it in the image as per the Resolution setting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the emphasis on the Resolution settings being the only control for the output, and me not really setting it to a vertical resolution, it opened my eyes to the mistake I made. Having rendered the  animation as Image Sequences with a vertical resolution initially, I opened Blender again and forgot to re-adjust the resolution in the Video sequence Editor type. Thank you.